# <a name=""> linking above sections instead of inside on firefox and mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

In firefox and my phone browser the `<a name="">` internal links are creating extra space at top of sections when I click on one of my nav bar links. It basically links above the section instead of inside of it.

It doesnt do this in chrome, I dont understand.

The Site:
**[www.sydluce.tk](http://www.sydluce.tk)**

Comment: link is broken..check the url..

Comment: The link is right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably because of the `line-height` the `a` produces. Add `display:block` to those `a` and you will be fine.

```
a[name] { display:block;}
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I didn't think of that! 